# python - Problem with object size in processing module

Tags: python, processing

I'm trying to make a program with the processing module for python which runs on a JVM. What I am looking for is to create a global object `A()` that could be used in the draw() method. Let me explain:

```
class A():
    # Some methods ...
    

class B():
    # Some methods ...


a_object = A()
def setup():
    #a_object = A() # if declared here cant't be accessed in draw()
    
    
def draw():
    b_ojbect = B()
```

My problem is that when I add more and more code to the class A, **the compiler doesn't let me create the object outside the setup function** (NullPointerException error), hence the object is not global anymore. Also, I would like to say that I want to be able to modify the object A through the object B, that's why I need it to be global.

Is there a way to solve this? Is it possible to create the object outside the setup function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Farsheed is right (+1): you'll need to use `global a_object` before using `a_object` inside a function. FWIW you can see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139974/using-processing-pgraphics-in-python-mode/61178724#61178724)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should use it. But keep in mind that using global objects is not recommended.

```
class A():
    # Some methods ...
    

class B():
    # Some methods ...


a_object = A()

def setup():
    global a_object
    ...

    
    
def draw():
    b_ojbect = B()
```

Comment: it is very recommended to use global variables in Processing sketches, you are *not* in a *software engineering* context, it works fine and keeps overall complexity lower :)

Comment: It would introduce race conditions, so no.

Comment: You probably don' t use Processing on a daily basis, mostly single threading with very few opportunities for race conditions! It is almost a platform pattern to use global variables and set them inside `setup()`. To suggest otherwise to people learning this tool is not productive.

Comment: That very few opportunities would be disastrous. That's why it's a bad idea.