# How to write this processing code in an alternative (beginner) way?

Tags: processing

How do I write the code (below) in an alternative (beginner) way? I don't wish to use createShape, setFill and addChild. Instead, any other way to perform the same thing?

```
grid = createShape(GROUP)
for i in range(C*R):
    self.cell = createShape(RECT, (i%C)*S, (i//C)*S, S, S)
    self.cell.setFill(colors[i] if i in filled else 210)
    grid.addChild(self.cell)
```

Comment: simplest: `for i in range(C*R):
    fill(colors[i] if i in filled else 210)
    rect(i%C)*S, (i//C)*S, S, S)` (indentation likely to need a fix)...this is the least efficient method though. You can try using [PGraphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139974/using-processing-pgraphics-in-python-mode/61178724#61178724) to cache the grid in `setup()` then simply render in `draw()` using `image()`

Comment: thanks! your code works, but there's an issue relating to a line that isn't there here!!! that is, this line - grid.addChild(cell)? How do I add it in your code?

Comment: Please read the [PShape Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) and run the example to get a feel for how it works. My example above redraws every single rectangle every single time while the PShape approach created the shapes (main `GROUP` shape with child `RECT` shapes (hence `addChild`)) once then probably rendered it with `shape()` in `draw()`. If you're drawing a grid you should also practice drawing it with lines  instead of rectangles (`beginShape()`/`vertex()`/`endShape()`) which will be more efficient (removing duplicates) but also a good mental puzzle ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're try to create a rectangle grid:

```
final int _numRows = 5;
final int _numCols = 7;

int l = 20;
int t = 20;
int w = 90;
int h = 60;
int hg = 10;
int vg = 10;
int left;
int top;
 
 void rectGrid() {
  for(int k = 0; k < _numRows; k++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < _numCols; j++){
   left = l + j*(w+vg);
   top = t + k*(h+hg);
   stroke(255);
   strokeWeight(2);
   fill(118);
   rect( left, top, w, h);
   }
  }
 }
 
 
void setup() { 
  size(800,500);
  background(0,0,245);
  rectGrid();
}

void draw() {
}
```

Comment: thanks! but how do I include 4th line of my code in your code i.e. self.cell.setFill(colors[i] if i in filled else 210)?

Comment: colors[i] is an array and you didn't provide that information.  Would be happy to add it if you supply it.

Comment: colors = [0] * (C)*(R+1) where,  C and R are number of columns and rows. Btw I'm using python.

Comment: I don't use Python, but it looks like that just initializes a color array; it does not appear to give any information about what the colors are. What does the grid look like?  Are there rectangles of different colors?

Comment: Yes, I've written a whole code. Shall I send over the code to u? for some reason, I don't want to post it here.

Comment: btw how do I add this line? grid.addChild(cell)

Comment: I don't think .addChild(cell) is necessary in Processing.  The rectangles are already added to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Adds a color array:

```
/*
 Adds color array to rectangle grid.
*/

final int _numRows = 5;
final int _numCols = 7;

int l = 20;
int t = 20;
int w = 90;
int h = 60;
int hg = 10;
int vg = 10;
int left;
int top;
int count = 0;
color[] c;

 void colorArray(){
   for(int x=0; x< _numRows*_numCols; x++){
     c[x] = color(random(255),random(255),random(255))
   }
 }  
 
 void rectGrid() {
  for(int k = 0; k < _numRows; k++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < _numCols; j++){
   left = l + j*(w+vg);
   top = t + k*(h+hg);
   stroke(255);
   strokeWeight(2);
   fill(c[count]);
   rect( left, top, w, h);
   count++;
   }
  }
 }
 
void setup() { 
  size(800,500);
  background(0,0,245);
  c = new color[_numCols*_numRows];
  colorArray();
  // Make sure the color array is filled first
  rectGrid();
}

void draw() {
}
```